# How to get id of created record in computed property?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have competed property in component which observes `model.events`

```
formatedEvents: function () { return this._formatEvents(); }.property('model.events')
```

And I have action which create event:

```
var event = this.get('store').createRecord('event', attr);
event.save().then((l) => {
  this.get('currentUser.events').then((_e)=> {
    _e.addObject(l);
  });
}).catch((err) => {
  lesson.deleteRecord();
  this.handleError(err);
});
```

`Ember` fires my computed property when record was created because there is `id` of new record is null. But I need to make `Ember` fires computed property after promise is fulfilled which returned `save()` then I will be able to get `id` in property.

Comment: I found out I can add observer `model.lessons.@each.id` to computed property but in this case `Ember` will fire property twice when record created and when `id` filled with value from server. I think it isn't so good, how could I fix it?

Comment: @kumkanillam, No, I need computed property because I use returned value in template.

Comment: You can wrap using  `Ember.run.once`. but in general you can try avoiding observer

Comment: How do you show the id in template?

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani I pass `formatedEvents` to `ember-fullcalendar` component.